# ClassicThesis: override options of a previously loaded classicthesis package

Tags: package-options, classicthesis

I have recently upgraded from Ubuntu 11.04 to Ubuntu 11.10. I also installed "vanilla" TexLive 2011 (instead of the old TexLive 2009 from the repositories) and upgraded it with `sudo tlmgr update --self -all` so all the packages are in the latest version. I currently need TexLive to write my PhD thesis and I use `classicthessis` package to do it.

In the new version of the `classicthesis`, v.3.0 that comes with TexLive 2011 the package is used by issuing just

```
\usepackage {classicthesis-preamble}
```

which is loaded as the first package in the preamble and then it sets everything and loads the `classicthesis` package (it is in the last line).

My question now is: **Is there a way to pass options to the `classicthesis` package and/or how can I disable some of the default options that `classicthesis-preamble` passes to the `classicthesis` package - FROM MY PREAMBLE (i.e. without altering the installed classicthesis files or creating their copies in my document folder and altering those?**

For example, classicthesis-preamble passes `drafting` option to the `classicthesis`

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{....,drafting,...}{classicthesis}
```

and I want to compile the my document without that option - but would prefer to do it from the preamble of my own document.

I tried reloading the `classicthesis` after `classisthesis-preamble` with my own set of options, expecting some error because `classicthesis` would be already called from the `classicthesis-preamble`:

```
\usepackage{classicthesis-preamble}
\usepackage[<some,option,set,that,does,not,contain,"drafting">]{classicthesis}
```

but there was no error, but no change in the options either. I tried using `\PassOptionsToPackage` but it can just *add additional options* to the existing ones. I tried googling for similar command that can *replace* instead of *add* options, but did not find one.

Answer (score 3):

André Miede's idea is that one should copy `classicthesis-preamble.sty` in the working directory and changes is to suit the needs for a particular job.

Not a very good idea, in my opinion, as the code in this package is quite intimidating for the novice and does not limit itself to some

```
\usepackage[<options>]{<package>}
```

lines, maybe with some auxiliary definitions. It's not very clear why saying

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{fleqn}{amsmath}           % math environments and more by the AMS 
 \RequirePackage{amsmath}
```

is to be preferred to the simpler

```
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
```

or what the novice user is supposed to do with

```
\ifthenelse{\boolean{cld@backref}}%
{%
                \PassOptionsToPackage{hyperpageref}{backref}
                \RequirePackage{backref} % to be loaded after hyperref package 
                   \renewcommand{\backreftwosep}{ and~} % seperate 2 pages
                   \renewcommand{\backreflastsep}{, and~} % seperate last of longer list
                   \renewcommand*{\backref}[1]{}  % Disable standard
                   \renewcommand*{\backrefalt}[4]{% Detailed backref
                      \ifcase #1 %
                         \backrefnotcitedstring%
                      \or%
                         \backrefcitedsinglestring{#2}%
                      \else%
                         \backrefcitedmultistring{#2}%
                      \fi}%
}{\relax}
```

which is code that should go in `classicthesis.sty`.

If you feel intimidated by `classicthesis-preamble.sty`, then *don't* load it and add the packages you need, passing the desired options directly to **classicthesis**.

For example

```
\documentclass[...]{scrbook}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}

\usepackage[eulerchapternumbers,subfig,beramono,eulermath,parts]{classicthesis}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{%draft, % = no hyperlinking at all (useful in b/w printouts)
    colorlinks=true, linktocpage=true, pdfstartpage=3, pdfstartview=FitV,%
    % uncomment the following line if you want to have black links (e.g., for printing)
    %colorlinks=false, linktocpage=false, pdfborder={0 0 0}, pdfstartpage=3, pdfstartview=FitV,% 
    breaklinks=true, pdfpagemode=UseNone, pageanchor=true, pdfpagemode=UseOutlines,%
    plainpages=false, bookmarksnumbered, bookmarksopen=true, bookmarksopenlevel=1,%
    hypertexnames=true, pdfhighlight=/O,%hyperfootnotes=true,%nesting=true,%frenchlinks,%
    urlcolor=webbrown, linkcolor=RoyalBlue, citecolor=webgreen, %pagecolor=RoyalBlue,%
    %urlcolor=Black, linkcolor=Black, citecolor=Black, %pagecolor=Black,%
    pdftitle={},%
    pdfauthor={},%
    pdfsubject={},%
    pdfkeywords={},%
    pdfcreator={pdfLaTeX},%
    pdfproducer={LaTeX with hyperref and classicthesis}%
}
```

which might be sufficient for many purposes.

Comment: Thanks! It looks exactly as you say - as it is intended to create you own copy of classicthesis-preamble. I agree with you that it is not quite novice-friendly but... Anyway, I don't quite understand your last sentence. What should one do or do not? Could you elaborate more on that? Thanks again for your answer.

Comment: @egred, Please, could you explain your last statement? It's probably my English, but I don't understand what you meant by "Just don't load classicthesis-preamble.sty and add the packages you need, passing the desired options directly to classicthesis."

Comment: he means do not use classicthesis-preamble. instead just pass the options you want to classictheis in your document.

Comment: Is `classicthesis-preamble.sty` still meant to be used? I never saw it [here](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/classicthesis/).

Comment: @JJD The last version has `classicthesis-config.tex`.